# run() method from Runnable is not working

Tags: java, android, runnable

i'm trying to build up a game, and i'm doing this with the help of a tutorial. My problem is, the run() method I show below is not working. I tried the sample code of the tutorial, it is exactly the same run() method and it works.
In my code, run() is never called and I don't get why.

```
package thisproject;

public class StartingClass extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener,
        MouseListener {
    private Builder builder;
    private Image image,currentSprite, character,characterWalk, background;
    private Graphics second;
    private URL base;
    private static Background bg1;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(800, 400);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
        frame.setTitle("Castle Fight");


        try {
            base = getDocumentBase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        // Image Setups
        background = getImage(base, "data/background2.png");
        character = getImage(base, "data/builder.png");
        currentSprite = character;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        bg1 = new Background(0, 0);    
        builder = new Builder();   

        Thread thread = new Thread();
        thread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("this thing");
            builder.update();
            bg1.update();
            repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        if (image == null) {
            image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            second = image.getGraphics();
        }


        second.setColor(getBackground());
        second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        second.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(second);


        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(background, bg1.getBgX(), bg1.getBgY(), this);
        g.drawImage(currentSprite, builder.getCenterX() - 61, builder.getCenterY() - 63, this);
    }

    }
}
```

Please, keep in mind that I took out the imports and the key events so the code didn't take much room, but I do have all the imports necessary.
Hopefully someone can give me some light on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never supply the `Runnable`.  Change

```
Thread thread = new Thread();
thread.start();
```

to

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();
```